# Tell me the flow of execution in the following scenario

Tags: c#-3.0

```
public class Temp
{
   List<T> values = new List<T>;

   static Temp()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("static constructor");
   }

   public Temp()
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("general constructor");
   }
}
```

Also please explain me when will the List object will be created and with what type it is created.

}

Answer (score 1):

It appears the field gets initialized first, then the static constructor is called, then the constructor.

```
class Test
{
    string variable = new Func<string>(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("field initializer");
        return "VARIABLE";
    })();

    static string staticvariable = new Func<string>(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("static field initializer");
        return "STATICVARIABLE";
    })();

    static Test()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("static constructor");
    }

    public Test()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("general constructor");
    }
}

Test t = new Test();
```

outuput:

static field initializer
static constructor
field initializer
general constructor

[edit]

Oops sorry, it was a non-static field and I didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

The static ctor will be called first.
Then values list will be second and the the ctor.
Read about beforefieldinit [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/beforefieldinit.html).

Comment: ex. if i create an obj of Temp class as 
 Temp obj = new Temp();

What does the list object will contain.
As it is generic, will it contains null values?
please suggest

Comment: It will not contain any values in it. Check the Count property. Also read this document to understand what linked list is: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf
If under the hood it got no values the List object itself is not null.
It just points to null.